# Local .pom File Not Registering?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies, pom.xml

I'm trying to convert a project from retrieving (successfully) online for a pom file to looking for it locally, but I'm getting this error as a result of performing a "Reload all Gradle Projects":

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'ImageConverter'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.test.gradle.plugins:test-gradle-plugins-common:2.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/test/gradle/plugins/test-gradle-plugins-common/2.0.1/test-gradle-plugins-common-2.0.1.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/test/gradle/plugins/test-gradle-plugins-common/2.0.1/test-gradle-plugins-common-2.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

This is a snippet of what I have in the root build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal() {
            metadataSources {
                mavenPom()
                artifact()
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.test.gradle.plugins:test-gradle-plugins-common:2.0.1'
    }
}
```

and the .pom file (which I copied verbatim from the previously working online version) starts out like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.gradle.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-gradle-plugins-common</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
```

I can copy the .pom path from the error message and `ls` it just fine, so the file definitely exists. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Is the error from gradle or from maven? How are you declaring this dependency inside maven?

Comment: @Lino This error is given as a result of performing a "Reload all Gradle Projects". I'm not sure of the answer to how I'm declaring the dependency. Is there another piece I need to add that I'm missing?